# Mocha "0 passing"

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I'm struggling using Mocha / Chai

Here is the code that I'm currently trying to execute (exemple from chai docs)

I have tried different way to call the file from 'run dev' command (as I saw on other post on stackoverflow), but none of them are working in my case.

Thanks in advance,

Paul

```
var expect = require('chai').expect,
  foo = 'bar',
  beverages = { tea: ['chai', 'matcha', 'oolong'] };

expect(foo).to.be.a('string');
expect(foo).to.equal('bar');
expect(foo).to.have.lengthOf(3);
expect(beverages).to.have.property('tea').with.lengthOf(3);
```

package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "test": "mocha ./test/app.spec.js"
  },
[...]
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^8.1.3"
  }
```

Comment: You should run run test command

Comment: do you mean "npm run test" ? it is what I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved starting over the mocha project and defining

```
"test": "mocha"
```

Paul